# Show that the linear transformation $T$ is continuously differentiable at every point, and in fact $T'(x) = T$ for every $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, linear-transformations, solution-verification

Let $T:\textbf{R}^{n}\to\textbf{R}^{m}$ be a linear transformation. Show that $T$ is continuously differentiable at every point, and in fact $T'(x) = T$ for every $x$.

**My solution**

According to this [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3691334/let-t-textbfrn-to-textbfrm-be-a-linear-transformation-show-that-th), $T$ is continuous because it is Lipschitz. On the other hand, due to the linearity of $T$, for every $x_{0}\in\textbf{R}^{n}$, we have that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to x_{0};x\neq x_{0}}\frac{\|T(x) - T(x_{0}) - T(x - x_{0})\|}{\|x - x_{0}\|} = \lim_{x\to x_{0};x\neq x_{0}}\frac{\|T(x) - T(x_{0}) - T(x)  + T(x_{0})\|}{\|x-x_{0}\|} = 0
\end{align*}

Hence $T'(x) = T$. Once the derivative is unique, the result follows.

Is the wording of my proof right? Is there another way to approach it?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: I think you still need to prove that the differential of $T$ is continuous. You have already done the hard part, though!

Comment: Another approach (since you asked) is to compute all partial derivatives of first order and check if they are continuous (this is equivalent to being continuously differentiable).

Comment: What does $T'(x)=T$ mean?  For functions from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are you trying to show that all linear functions are exponential functions?  If $T:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is given by $T(x) = x$, then $T'(x)=1$ (so $T'(x)\neq T(x)$).

Comment: @Michael in higher dimensions, the notation for the derivatives vary from text to text, but $T'(x), dT(x), dT_x, DT(x), DT_x$ or any other similar "derivative-type notation" usually refer to the derivative of $T$ at the point $x$, which by definition is a linear map. In the case of functions $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$, the derivative in this "new" sense, is again a linear map $Df_x \in \mathcal{L}(\Bbb{R}, \Bbb{R})$, but because of the isomorphism $ \mathcal{L}(\Bbb{R}, \Bbb{R}) \cong \Bbb{R}$, the isomorphism being $S \mapsto S(1)$, we can simply think of the derivative in one-dimension

Comment: as a number, namely $Df_x(1) \in \Bbb{R}$. This coincides with what we usually write as $f'(x)$ in standard single-variable calculus.

Comment: Again, what does $T'(x)=T$ mean?  It looks like they are using $T$ as both a matrix and a function.  It would make more sense to define $T(x)=Ax$ and then prove the derivative of $T$ at each point $x$ is the matrix $A$.

Comment: @Michael My preferred notation is to write it as: for every $x \in \Bbb{R}^n$, $DT_x = T$. This is an equality of linear transformations, i.e for all $x,y \in \Bbb{R}^n$, $DT_x(y) = T(y)$. Which basically says that "a linear transformation is its own best linear approximation". In any case,  the statement of the question is correct (apart from perhaps some potential notational confusion with single variable, which the OP doesn't seem to have), and OP's proof is correct and almost complete (cont)

Comment: (OP: you proved that $T$ is differentiable at every point with $DT_x = T$, but you havent proved continuous differentiability... but of course this is trivial since derivative is a constant equal to $T$, i.e the map $DT: x \mapsto DT_x = T$ is constant, hence continuous, which precisely proves that $T$ is continuously differentiable (and in fact $C^{\infty}$))

Comment: @peek-a-boo : Lots of esoteric notation to represent something simple. Usually people think of a derivative of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ at a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ as a vector, not a linear map. For example, $f'=f$ is a classic ODE. I see how your notation is consistent, but I don't see a reason for using it.